# merge problem in docker-compose and .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm working on a project that has two branches, develop and production.
The .gitlab-ci.yml has two stages on production branch but three different stages on develop branch.
Also the docker-compose file is different on this two branches.
When I merge develop to production branch that two files replaced with wrong version.
What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prepare a same file for .gitlab-ci that has all stages and make these pipelines run only when on true branches, with this lines:

```
  only:
    - develop
```

and you should prepare two docker-compose and on stage's script, point to the right file on each stage.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Kasra, in addition you can separate develop and production pipelines each on a separate yml files. take a look at the example here:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image

and make sure to use after every stage that is branch-specific :

> ```
>   only:
>     - develop
> ```

Comment: thanks. but how .releaserc.yml run piplines on ci/cd ? Shouldn't the file name be .gitlab-ci exactly?

Comment: by adding below in  the original .gitlab-ci 
include:
  - local: <path to .releaserc.yml>

Comment: follow the example it was very helpful for me :https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image